# How can I put typer commands in separate modules without becoming sub-commands?

Tags: python, typer

Here is a fudge which works but causes problems with option position flexibility and help:

*main.py:*

```py
import typer
import mycommand
app = typer.Typer()
app.add_typer(mycommand.app, name='mycommand')
@app.command()
def othercmd():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

*mycommand.py:*

```py
from typing import List
import typer
app = typer.Typer()
@app.callback(invoke_without_command=True)   # Not a sub command - run this by default
def mycommand(files: List[str] = typer.Argument(...), name: str = typer.Option(None)):
    if name: print(f'Hello {name}')
    print(files)
```

You can run this now with `python main.py mycommand --name Butty myfile.txt`.
However, attempting to run with `python main.py mycommand myfile.txt --name Butty` will load the option into the files argument.

Issuing `main.py mycommand --help` reveals why; there is an extra command and args expected after the callback options and arguments:

```
Usage: main.py mycommand [OPTIONS] FILES... COMMAND [ARGS]...

Arguments:
  FILES...  [required]

Options:
  --name TEXT
  --help       Show this message and exit.
```

Is there a way to add a command to typer in a separate module as a "default" command which would react the same as using `@app.command()`?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a way. Not sure if this is how they meant to use it, but this works for most.

*main.py*

```
import typer
import mycommand

app = typer.Typer()

app.command()(mycommand.yourcommand)

@app.command()
def othercmd():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

and your other module may look like below. The need of typer decorators also vanish.

*mycommand.py*

```
from typing import List
import typer

def yourcommand(files: List[str] = typer.Argument(...), name: str = typer.Option(None)):
    if name: print(f'Hello {name}')
    print(files)
```

This [Github Issue Post](https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/178#issuecomment-738853400) is what you maybe looking for, though I've put the solution out anyway.